# Why can't I have multiple get methods in asp.net webapi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am building a small app using AngularJS and WebAPI.

Usecase: I am passing a string parameter from the drop-down ng-change event to a function called getcatdetails(selectedcategory) in controller.js and service.js calls WEBAPI.

Problem: When I add additional method in WEB API the code doesn't get fired. When I put the break point in controller and Service.js it looks fine but the call doesn't happen from Service to WEBAPI.

Here is the code..

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectedcategory" ng-options="item for item in catlist" ng-change="getcatdetails(selectedcategory)">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

Controller.js

```
 $scope.getcatdetails = function (selectedcategory) {
    var catdetails = CategoryService.getcatdetails(selectedcategory);
 }
```

Service.js

```
this.getcatdetails= function (selectedcategory) {
    return $http.get("/api/ProductAPI/getcatdetails" + selectedcategory);
}
```

WEB API method

```
[Route("/api/ProductAPI/getcatdetails")]
public string getcatdetails(string selectedcategory)
{
    return selectedcategory;
}
```

Please help me ...i am totally struck

---

This is what I tried by I am still unable to call WEB API method..

```
Service.js

 this.getcatdetails = function () {
   return $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'api/productapi/getcatdetails', data: '"' + selectedcategory + '"' })
}


WEB API Method..

    [Route("api/ProductAPI/getcatdetails/{selectedcategory}")]
   public string getcatdetails(string  selectedcategory){

       return selectedcategory;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the category as part of the url, so chnage your method to be

```
[Route("api/ProductAPI/getcatdetails/{selectedcategory} ")]

public string getcatdetails(string selectedcategory)
{
    return selectedcategory;
}
```